# Categorize array of objects into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array and I need to map this array into an array of its children.

```
var data = [{
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'BMW',
    value: 2000
  },
  {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'Fiat',
    value: 542
  },
  {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'Mercedes',
    value: 745
  },
  {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'Toyota',
    value: 965
  },
  {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'Honda',
    value: 754
  }, {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'VW',
    value: 123
  },
  {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'Ford',
    value: 200
  },
  {
    name: 'Fruits',
    content: 'Apple',
    value: 500
  }, {
    name: 'Fruits',
    content: 'Orange',
    value: 769
  }, {
    name: 'Fruits',
    content: 'Banana',
    value: 120
  }, {
    name: 'Fruits',
    content: 'Strawberry',
    value: 48
  }, {
    name: 'Fruits',
    content: 'Mango',
    value: 653
  },
  {
    name: 'Colors',
    content: 'Red',
    value: 965
  }, {
    name: 'Colors',
    content: 'Black',
    value: 931
  }, {
    name: 'Colors',
    content: 'BMW',
    value: 423
  }, {
    name: 'Colors',
    content: 'BMW',
    value: 964
  }, {
    name: 'Colors',
    content: 'BMW',
    value: 436
  }
]
```

The end result what I want must be like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "Children Array",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Cars",
        children: [
          {
            name: "BMW",
            value: 2000
          }, 
          {
            name: "Fiat",
            value: 542
          }, 
          {
          ...
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Fruits",
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Apple',
            value: 500
          }, 
          {
            name: 'Orange',
            value: 769
          }, 
          {
            ...
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        name: "Colors",
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Red',
            value: 965
          }, 
          {
            ...
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is what I did.

```js
var data = [{
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'BMW',
    value: 2000
  },
  {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'Fiat',
    value: 542
  },
  {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'Mercedes',
    value: 745
  },
  {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'Toyota',
    value: 965
  },
  {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'Honda',
    value: 754
  }, {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'VW',
    value: 123
  },
  {
    name: 'Cars',
    content: 'Ford',
    value: 200
  },
  {
    name: 'Fruits',
    content: 'Apple',
    value: 500
  }, {
    name: 'Fruits',
    content: 'Orange',
    value: 769
  }, {
    name: 'Fruits',
    content: 'Banana',
    value: 120
  }, {
    name: 'Fruits',
    content: 'Strawberry',
    value: 48
  }, {
    name: 'Fruits',
    content: 'Mango',
    value: 653
  },
  {
    name: 'Colors',
    content: 'Red',
    value: 965
  }, {
    name: 'Colors',
    content: 'Black',
    value: 931
  }, {
    name: 'Colors',
    content: 'BMW',
    value: 423
  }, {
    name: 'Colors',
    content: 'BMW',
    value: 964
  }, {
    name: 'Colors',
    content: 'BMW',
    value: 436
  }
]

const layer1 = _.uniqWith(_.map(data, (item) => {
  return item.name
}), _.isEqual)

const newArray = [{
  name: 'Children Array',
  children: _.map(layer1, (item) => {
    return {
      name: item,
      children: _.map(data, (item) => {
        return {

        }
      })
    }
  })
}]

console.log(newArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

I do not know how to proceed with the second children layer.

Please advice.

Comment: Shouldn't you `return { name: item.content, value: item.value }` for each child?

Comment: I guess not. I need to compare this value with the layer1 value, filter out data and map them. But not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could group the data and give the result the final layout.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'Cars', content: 'BMW', value: 2000 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'Fiat', value: 542 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'Mercedes', value: 745 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'Toyota', value: 965 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'Honda', value: 754 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'VW', value: 123 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'Ford', value: 200 }, { name: 'Fruits', content: 'Apple', value: 500 }, { name: 'Fruits', content: 'Orange', value: 769 }, { name: 'Fruits', content: 'Banana', value: 120 }, { name: 'Fruits', content: 'Strawberry', value: 48 }, { name: 'Fruits', content: 'Mango', value: 653 }, { name: 'Colors', content: 'Red', value: 965 }, { name: 'Colors', content: 'Black', value: 931 }, { name: 'Colors', content: 'BMW', value: 423 }, { name: 'Colors', content: 'BMW', value: 964 }, { name: 'Colors', content: 'BMW', value: 436 }],
    result = _(data)
        .groupBy('name')
        .map((group, name) => 
            ({ name, children: _.map(group, ({ content: name, value }) => ({ name, value })) }))
        .value(),
    final = [{ name: "Children Array", children: result }];

console.log(final);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do that with ES6 only via [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) & [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var data = [{ name: 'Cars', content: 'BMW', value: 2000 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'Fiat', value: 542 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'Mercedes', value: 745 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'Toyota', value: 965 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'Honda', value: 754 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'VW', value: 123 }, { name: 'Cars', content: 'Ford', value: 200 }, { name: 'Fruits', content: 'Apple', value: 500 }, { name: 'Fruits', content: 'Orange', value: 769 }, { name: 'Fruits', content: 'Banana', value: 120 }, { name: 'Fruits', content: 'Strawberry', value: 48 }, { name: 'Fruits', content: 'Mango', value: 653 }, { name: 'Colors', content: 'Red', value: 965 }, { name: 'Colors', content: 'Black', value: 931 }, { name: 'Colors', content: 'BMW', value: 423 }, { name: 'Colors', content: 'BMW', value: 964 }, { name: 'Colors', content: 'BMW', value: 436 }]

const groupData = (d) => {
  let g = Object.entries(d.reduce((r,c)=>(r[c.name]=[...r[c.name]||[], c],r),{}))
  return g.reduce((r,c) => (r.children.push(
     {name: c[0], children: c[1]}), r),{name: "Children Array", children:[]})}

console.log(groupData(data))
```

The idea is via the first grouping to get an object with the `name groups` and after that you simply get the `entries` on that object and `reduce` on them to get the final result.

Also you start the main reduce with your predefined object etc.